# Incrementing record property in Elm

Tags: elm

**What's best way to increment property of record in Elm?**

Let's say, that I have simple model like this -

```
model : Model
model =
    { counter = 0 }
```

And if I wanted to have in update something like this

```
update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    NoOp -> model
    Increment -> { model | counter = model.counter + 1}
```

Now, I know I can as well write my Increment as

```
Increment -> { model | counter = .counter model + 1 }
```

But I am wondering, if there is a way to do it similarly to this

```
Increment -> { model | counter += 1} || Increment -> { model | counter++ }
```

or even something like this

```
Increment -> { model | counter = counter + 1 }
```

Sorry if this is stupid question, I am just starting with Elm and would like some insight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first example is probably the most idiomatic way to do it in Elm:

```elm
{ model | counter = model.counter + 1}
```

There are no `+=` or `++` operators in Elm like there are in other languages. You'll often see Elm purposely choose to keep the language syntax small, and these operators arguably increase the learning curve and could also introduce confusion since their use in other languages imply mutation, which is absent in Elm.

The `{ model | counter = .counter model + 1 }` example is valid but you'll usually only use a record field as a getter when using it as a function, like in mapping.

```elm
-- This example would map a list of counter values from a list of models
List.map .counter models
```

Comment: That being said, there *are* a number of libraries for Elm that seek to emulate lenses as we know them from Haskell (such as `focus`).